# pandas: prevent column dtype conversion when changing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example code, where I receive a `pd.Series` (`ds`) that normally contains string data, but could also contain numeric data or np.nan. Whatever the input, I want to assign text to the column. However, if `ds` has only `np.nan`, I receive a FutureWarning:

```
FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value <some_value> has dtype incompatible with `float64`, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
```

Therefore I apply `.astype(str)`, which gives `'nan'`, which I then want again to change to `np.nan`. This however changes the dtype back to `float64`, if only `np.nan` values are included in the series.

Is there a way to prevent this, or another better way to achieve this?

Some dummy code showing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#let's assume ds is as follows on the input
ds = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan])

ds = ds.astype(str).replace('nan', np.nan)
#because only nan, type is now float64 again...

mask = ds.isna() # this is why I need/want np.nan values

ds[mask] = np.where(ds == 'asdf', 'aaa', 'bbb') # yields FutureWarning
```

Am I missing something something obvious maybe?

I tried without the `.replace('nan', np.nan)`, but then I can't use `.isna()` anymore and have to use a less elegant `ds == 'nan'` to achieve the same.

With the current pandas version it works, except the FutureWarning. But I want to write the code already future-proof right now.

Comment: ```ds = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan]).astype("string")```
have you tried using "string" which is a nullable dtype ?

Comment: For the rest of the code I do not understand what you're trying to achieve since the data is missing.

Comment: np.nan is of type float. You can verify this by print(type(np.nan)) . You can try [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)   by feeding it a list to filter.

Comment: @ombk, `.astype("string")` does it, that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that it differs from `.astype(str)`. Thanks!

Comment: geen probleem! :)